# Encoding of the plain text document was not declared on route refresh

Tags: html, reactjs, webpack

In prod build, I am encountering `encoding of the plain text document was not declared` on page refresh and fresh navigation for current url routes.

For example, I can safely navigate to `localhost:8080` and access all the url paths by click navigation: `/path-a`, `/path-b`, and `/path-c`, but when any of the paths are refreshed, the encoding issue reappears.

The following code is included in the `index.html`:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
```

On `dev`, I can safely refresh on each route without experiencing any issue.

Comment: try this one,`<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />`

Comment: No difference. Since UTF-8 is declared, the whole site should have the same meta tag. This could either be an issue with webpack configuration or `react-router-dom`

Comment: "In prod build" - does this mean a production build served by an external web server?

Comment: `"build": "webpack --mode production",` so production build through webpack.